# Invalid Template File

Tags: magento2

I keep getting this error in system log:

> Invalid template file:
>   'Inchoo_SocialConnect::inchoo/socialconnect/google/‌​button.phtml' in
>   module: 'Inchoo_SocialConnect' block's name:
>   'inchoo_socialconnect_login_google_button' [] []

i also get these two main.INFO:

> Cache file with merged layout:
>   LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_2999a55d7d9f00b9a016b5e16762ce70a and handles
>   default, customer_account_login: Please correct the XML data and try
>   again.
>
> main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout:
>   LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_20a98983867a1770682b48d9a0ad63441 and handles
>   1column: Please correct the XML data and try again.

snippet my layout file:

```
    <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::inchoo/socialconnect/login.phtml">
                <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Google\Button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login_google_button" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::inchoo/socialconnect/google/‌​button.phtml"/>
    </block>
```

button.phtml file:

```
<div class="clearer">
    <div class="inchoo-socialconnect-facebook">
        <div class="inchoo-socialconnect-facebook-inner">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->_getButtonUrl()); ?>"><?php echo $this->_getButtonText(); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="inchoo-socialconnect-facebook-right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

button.phtml gets called from login.phtml:

```
<div class="buttons-set">
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('inchoo_socialconnect_login_google_button'); ?>
      <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the exact path of your template file?

Comment: @RonakChauhan fullpath: 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\project-community-edition\app\code\Inchoo\SocialConnect\view\frontend\templates\inchoo\socialconnect\google\button.phtml'

Comment: set Template like this : `Inchoo_SocialConnect::socialconnect/login.phtml`

Comment: and would "inchoo_socialconnect_login_google_button" be "Inchoo_SocialConnect::socialconnect/google/button‌​.phtml"?

Comment: yes, just need to remove module name as i gave in path

Answer (score 1):

set template like this:

`Inchoo_SocialConnect::socialconnect/login.phtml`
`Inchoo_SocialConnect::socialconnect/google/‌​button.phtml`

Comment: just tried it, same error unfortunately

Comment: are you able to call block for login?

Comment: no: "Invalid template file: 'Inchoo_SocialConnect::socialconnect/login.phtml' in module: 'Inchoo_SocialConnect' block's name: 'inchoo_socialconnect_login' [] []"

Comment: first remove button block from xml and try only single block of that login

Comment: I'll give it a go

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason. Magento 2 doesn't like button.phtml being in a custom folder (Inchoo_SocialConnect::**google**/‌​button.phtml), so i moved it to the root of the templates folder along side login.phtml (Inchoo_SocialConnect::login.phtml) so the template file path for button.phtml is now:

```
Inchoo_SocialConnect::button.phtml
```

I called it like this:

```
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('inchoo_socialconnect_login_button'); ?>
```

and my layout file is as follows:

```
<body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer.login.container">
        <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::login.phtml" cacheable="false"/>          
        <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Pixelpin\Button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login_button" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::button.phtml" cacheable="false"/>     
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

So when I was experiencing this issue in my view directory I had set up my template directory as **template** instead of **templates** please make sure spelling is correct.